# app:processReleaseResources FAILED while creating android release build

Tags: android, react-native

I am creating android release build from my react-native app. Everytime it gives me msg `app:processReleaseResources FAILED` in console.

I have tried

```
rm -rf android/app/src/main/res/drawable-*
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false \
--entry-file index.js \
--bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle \
--assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

but got no luck. I don't know what I am doing wrong or missing.

I expect release build created successfully but it is giving me `app:processReleaseResources FAILED` everytime.

Comment: Please show me the complete log.

Comment: can you please share the logs